# For loop in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

Is there a quick, easy, and efficient way of running iterations in this for loop in parallel?

```
for i in `seq 1 5000`; do
  repid="$(printf "%05d" "$i")"
  inp="${repid}.inp"
  out="${repid}.out"
  /command "$inp" "$out"
done
```

Comment: Just put `&` after the `/command` line. Are you sure your system can handle 5000 instances of the process, though?

Comment: I do not want to run all 5000 instances all at once as that is impossible. I am thinking within the lines of how, for instance in R, certain packages can handle embarrassingly parallel workload in loops this using sockets or forking (https://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-r-loops-for-windows-and-linux/). Is there something like this in bash?

Comment: See `xargs -P` or [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take advantage of all your lovely CPU cores that you paid Intel so handsomely for, turn to **GNU Parallel**:

```
seq -f "%05g" 5000 | parallel -k echo command {}.inp {}.out
```

If you like the look of that, run it again without the `-k` (which keeps the output in order) and without the `echo`. You may need to enclose the command in single quotes:

```
seq -f "%05g" 5000 | parallel '/command {}.inp {}.out'
```

It will run 1 instance per CPU core in parallel, but, if you want say 32 in parallel, use:

```
seq ... | parallel -j 32 ...
```

If you want an *"estimated time of arrival"*, use:

```
parallel --eta ...
```

If you want a progress meter, use:

```
parallel --progress ...
```

---

If you have `bash` version 4+, it can zero-pad brace expansions. And if your `ARGMAX` is big enough, so you can more simply use:

```
parallel 'echo command {}.inp {}.out' ::: {00001..05000}
```

You can check your `ARGMAX` with:

```
sysctl -a kern.argmax
```

and it tells you how many bytes long your parameter list can be. You are going to need 5,000 numbers at 5 digits plus a space each, so 30,000 minimum.

---

If you are on **macOS**, you can install **GNU Parallel** with **homebrew**:

```
brew install parallel
```

Comment: `echo {00001..050000000} |parallel -d" " 'echo command {}.inp {}.out'`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `seq 1 5000`; do
  repid="$(printf "%05d" "$i")"
  inp="${repid}.inp"
  out="${repid}.out"
  /command "$inp" "$out" &
done
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.